# The weird result of istream_iterator in C++

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istream_iterator<int> in_iter(cin);
    istream_iterator<int> eof;
    vector<int> vin;
    /*while (in_iter!=eof)
    {
        vin.push_back(*in_iter++);
    }*/
    istream_iterator<int> in_iter2(cin), eof2;
    vector<int> vin2(in_iter2,eof2);
    return 0;
}
```

When I input `1 2 3 c` (the last element 'c' is to make the cin state to EOF)to the program,finally,`vin2` will contain elements: `2 3`;However,when I annotate the declaration of variable `in_iter`,the same input will make `vin2` contain elements:`1 2 3`;How does the declaration of variable `in_iter` make effect to this program?Thanks!

Comment: The proper way to enter EOF is to... enter EOF. It's ctrl-Z or ctrl-D depending on which OS you're using. Entering c will not make anything EOF.

Comment: "when I annotate the declaration of variable in_iter" - what does that mean?

Comment: @TonyD, I'm thinking comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binding of an `istream_iterator` to an `istream` causes one value to be read from the `istream`, and stored in the iterator.  This is necessary so that dereferening the iterator can give a value.  So if you bind 2 `istream_iterators` to the same `istream`, 2 values will be read.

It's rarely useful to have 2 active istream iterators bound to the same istream.

As an mildly interesting experiment, see what happens if you create both `in_iter` and `in_iter2`, both bound to `cin`, and initialize your vector with `in_iter` (or whichever one was created first).